# Push View Controller When Notification Is Tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a Storyboard app with a UINavigationController as its Storyboard Entry Point. Its normal main view is a ViewController called "ViewController". What I want to have happen is push the controller named "JustNotifications" when a user taps the incoming notification. However, nothing happens as of now. What am I missing?

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *notificationData = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    
    // Extract data from the notification payload
    NSString *title = notificationData[@"title"];
    NSString *description = notificationData[@"description"];

    // Get a reference to the navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    // Find the currently visible view controller in the navigation stack
    UIViewController *currentViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController;

    // Perform the segue
    [currentViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowJustNotificationsSegue" sender:self];

    // Call the completion handler
    completionHandler();
}
```

Comment: What class is this code in? Is this delegate being called at all? Have you used the debugger to step through this code and see what it does and where thing don't go as expected?

Comment: @HangarRash it’s in appdelegate where the remote notifications normally are handled

Comment: They are remote

Comment: So back to my first comment above. Have you used the debugger to see what your code is actually doing? Update your question with details about what is actually happening in your code.

Comment: @HangarRash The code runs, I added some logs in the console, and everything is there, it just isn't pushing the view controller

Comment: Then either `navigationController` or `currentViewController` is nil. Checking those need to be part of the debugging. Also verify the segue is setup correctly in the storyboard.

Comment: `UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSLog(@"Navigate%@", rootNavigationController);` This returns NULL...Actually both that and current are returning NULL

Comment: @HangarRash When I look at IB, I see Navigation Controller Scene. The controller in that scene is UINavigationController, doesn't contain a Storyboard ID, and is check marked for "Is initial view controller". There's an arrow pointing to it from the left for "Storyboard entry point"

Comment: `self.window` could be nil. Modern apps (iOS 13+) do not use `UIApplicationDelegate window` any more due to the use of scenes.

Comment: @HangarRash Correct, window is nil

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
NSDictionary *notificationData = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    
    NSString *title = notificationData[@"title"];
    NSString *description = notificationData[@"description"];
    
    // Instantiate the JustNotifications view controller
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    JustNotifications *newViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"JustNotifications"];
    newViewController.titleText = title;
    newViewController.descriptionText = description;
    
    // Wrap the JustNotifications view controller in a new navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newViewController];
    
    // Present the navigation controller modally
    UIViewController *rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController;
    [rootViewController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    completionHandler();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain what was wrong with the code in your question and explain how your answers solves the issue. That makes for a much better answer to help others.